# Ionic Framework Login with php RestAPI

Tags: angularjs, oauth-2.0, ionic-framework, restful-authentication, hybrid-mobile-app

I am building an app which needs to be talk to a spring backend to log in users. I did a cURL post of

```
curl -X POST -vu sampleapp:appkey http://sampleurl/oauth/token -H "Accept: application/json" -d "password=pwd&username=sampleuname&grant_type=password&scope=read%20write&client_secret=appkey&client_id=sampleapp"
```

I get the desired response as :

```
{
"access_token":"xxx",
"token_type":"bearer",
"refresh_token":"xxx",
"expires_in":43199,
"scope":"read write"
}
```

In the app end, I have a button which calls the function below . I am getting CORS error (`401 Unauthorized`) as of now but I still can't help feel that I'm not calling it in a correct way.Here's what I have

```
 $scope.login = function() {

                $http({
                  method: "post", 
                  url: "http://sampleurl/oauth/token", 
                  data:  "client_id=" + clientId + "&client_secret=" + clientSecret + "password=pwd&username=sampleuser&grant_type=password" + "&scope=read%20write",
                  withCredentials: true,
                  headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
                    }
                })                
                   .success(function(data) {
                        accessToken = data.access_token;
                        $location.path("/secure");
                    })
                    .error(function(data, status) {
                        alert("ERROR: " + data);
                    });

    }
```

I am just not sure if the way I'm implementing it is correct. I have looked into all possible online resources but 99% of them are about integrating with Social Network accounts. I want something which will let me log in and access profile information exposed through

```
/user/{username}
```

I have looked into the option of using ng-Resource but I still don't know how to make the authentication call. For a call to twitter/facebook api , the format followed is not giving me the desired result.

Any help or link to resources will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you are getting CORS error then probably the problem is with the server.

Comment: @BipinBhandari I'm using a spring backend and I've researched it to some level and I don't think the issue is with the server. I might be wrong but I have included the allow origin access headers to the server which should take care of the issue

Comment: If you are getting cors error then its definitely server error. Your server is not allowing cross origin requests. If requests are working on curl but not on angular despite same request headers and body (you should inspect request send by angular) then it is CORS error for sure.

Comment: @BipinBhandari i am looking into the cors issue with using jsonp. However, is my url for the call correct ? Should it be the curl post call or the url I am passing in the $http resource ?